# piping find to head

Tags: bash

I have a script to read the first line of any text file with a certain extension within a certain folder, recursively, but it doesn't work. The head command is non-functional.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
(find ~/SpaceMonkey/MATLAB/Luo-Rudy -name '*.m') | head –n 1 > /dev/null
sleep 300
done
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you intend is to use `find` to run `head` for you.

Replace your existing find line with :

```
find ~/SpaceMonkey/MATLAB/Luo-Rudy -name '*.m' -exec head -n 1 '{}' \;
```

This will run `head` to get the first line on every matching file. You can redirect the output by simply adding `> destination` to the end of the command.

Comment: What is the purpose of the string with brackets and the escaped line end? Just curious, since it works.

Comment: The brackets are replaced with the name of the matched file and the semi-colon tells exec where the command ends. The quotes and backslash are to "protect" them from the shell.A 'man find' from the command line reveals much - particularly the EXAMPLES section.

Comment: Excellent. I figured that was the case for the escaped semicolon, but was stumped about the brackets. I found the answer in the ACTIONS section of the man file after you told me, but that man file is a beast. find seems like a pretty powerful command.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems with your script.

First, you're sending the final output from `head` to `/dev/null`, so you won't see anything from head at all.

Second, you're not actually opening the files, you're just passing the *list of files* found by `find` into `head`, so even if you remove the `> /dev/null` you'll just see the name of the first file. If `head` reads from stdin, it treats stdin as the 'file', not as a list of files to process.

Instead, you'll want to do something more like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$HOME/SpaceMonkey/MATLAB/Luo-Rudy"
while true
do
    for filename in $(find $DIR -name '*.m')
    do
        head -n 1 $filename
        # or if you want the filename listed too:
        #echo "$filename $(head -n 1 $filename)"
    done
    sleep 300
done
```

Note also that if you used the `zsh` shell, you could achieve this more simply:

```
head -n 1 $DIR/**/*.m
```

The `zsh` shell (and some others) allows recursive file globbing, to let you pass all `.m` files (recursively) to `head` as command line arguments in one go.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the zsh one-liner. I have zsh on all my machines, but I tend to use bash for scripting. I know bash is a less sane scripting language, but everyone has it. Both solutions are good, but the bash one-liner in the other answer is more immediately applicable, so I'm selecting that. The zsh feature is really cool though.